# Objects in table load on 4G network but not over WiFi

Tags: swift, uitableview, connection, wifi, alamofire

I have 2 tables in my application.

> In the first table, I display some restaurant names
>
> In the second some item names.

I load these items from an SQL database. In my application I have added the Alamofire framework. Now whenever I open the application using Wifi I get an error which takes me to the app delegate. When I use my 4G network everything is fine.

The following line is marked from Xcode as an error.

```
cell.restaurantImage!.image = restaurants[indexPath.row].image!
```

When I remove the (!) from the .image! it loads data from the wifi network but images are not displayed.

How can I overcome this error?

Comment: Please add the error from xcode. Also, you can only explicitly unwrap image if it is indeed an optional. Are you sure image is an optional?

Comment: hey i am new to Xcode and I have stuck. unfortunately i cant post a photo in stack overflow yet. it sais Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)

Comment: the problem is that a couple of days ago it was working on my wifi network. now it only works over 4g

Comment: Your console probably gives you more info

Comment: as i said mate, a couple of days ago it was working..do u have any idea why is this happening now?

Comment: No, except from the wifi network connection not working properly. But, to figure out such things, "not working" is usually not enough info. Check your console for more